# Microchip DV102013 Not Recognized by Computer

Tags: usb

I am attempting to use the DV102013, a multi-touch PCAP by Mircochip, but when I connect it to the computer, there is no sign that the computer recognizes the device.  The LED on the device lights up to show there's power but no driver installation came up, it doesn't show in the device manager, and the MTCH6303 Utility that the device works with also does not recognize it.

Has anyone had an issue like this? Is there a general fix for issues like this?

Comment: Please provide datasheet links for any devices referenced. Is it USB or what?

Comment: It is USB, there are I2C pins on there for communicating with a microcontroller, but I am trying to use it with their premade software "MTCH6303 Utility."  The datasheet they provide is: http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/40001803A.pdf and the product brief http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/MTCH6303%20Product%20Brief.pdf and the quick start guide http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/DV102013%20Quick%20Start%20Guide.pdf

Comment: At this point, it's really not an electronics question, but a usage question. I've flagged it for migration to Super User.